# undersampling in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, sampling

I have imbalanced dataset and I want to perform undersampling. I have 2000 instances out of which 150 are positive and 1850 are negative.  I have performed undersampling i.e.,  I have randomly selected 150 -ve instances. Now, I have total 300 instances. After applying machine learning classifiers on these 300 instances, I am getting 79% accuracy.

Please let me know if these results will be valid and acceptable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you trained and tested on the same set (the 300 examples you chose). This is generally not recommended, and the results don't mean much.

Make sure to set aside about 10% of the data, for testing. Then, you can train on your train set, and test on the test set, and get a more accurate evaluation of your error/accuracy.

Do bear in mind, that if your test set has the same distribution as your data (1 positive to 12 negatives), a "stupid" classifier which always classifies 'no' will get 92.5% accuracy.  Then, 79% accuracy would be bad.

Look at other measures like [roc-auc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) to better asses your classifier, in imbalanced cases.

EDIT: 
As mentioned in the comments, roc-auc might not be the best option. AUC-PR could be better in highly skewed datasets (such as yours). I also like f1-macro, which is an unweighted average of both labels' f1-scores.

Comment: I was ready to upvote for correctly mentioning that a test-set should be used but then saw that you proposed using AUC-ROC for imbalanced classed. That is not useful (in general) and can be misleading in the case of imbalanced data, if anything using AUC-PR from Precision-Recall curves should be more insightful.

Comment: @usεr11852 I am not sure why you say that. I believe that AUC-PR is better as well, but AUC-ROC gets good results as well. As I understand, maximizing the former will maximize the latter, but not the other way around. http://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/he/PDFfiles/ImbalancedLearning.pdf

Comment: We know that if a curve dominates another in PR space it will do in ROC space too while the opposite does not hold (Davis & James, 2006). I have read the He & Garcia paper multiple times and if anything the authors say *In the case of highly skewed data sets, it is observed that the ROC curve may provide an overly optimistic view of an algorithm’s performance. Under such situations, the PR curves can provide a more informative representation of performance assessment*. I recently skim-read the MSc thesis of Brent van Riet on *Measuring the performance of CRM models*, it quite a good overview.

Comment: See also: Jeni et al. *Facing Imbalanced Data Recommendations for the Use of Performance Metric*. (Just to be clear, I don't think it is outright wrong to use AUC-ROC. I think though that as a singular advice point is not very useful.)

Comment: @usεr11852 in my defense, I wrote "look at other measures like..." and didn't conclude. I'll edit in a clear way to improve the answer.

Comment: @usεr11852 Oh, and I'll make sure to read what you added here. I am actually writing a thesis on classification of bacteria, with a highly skewed dataset :)

Comment: Cool (+1). When you finish it and it is published online drop a comment here with a link. I am always interested in reading MSc theses; on quite a few cases I find their presentation/exposition much better than the one of analogous papers. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two possible reasons why you might want to undersample: for training or for testing.

First of all, when training your classifier, if one class dominates the data, then the cost function will be dominated by how well the classifier predicts that particular class. So the parameters of the classifier will be optimized more heavily towards detecting that class, and it won't "care" so much about correctly rejecting that class because there are fewer instances in the data where that is an issue. In other words, if we consider the more prevalent class to be "positive", the classifier is getting biased towards a higher *rate* of hits and false alarms, which it can afford to do because the *number* of potential false alarms is low given the prevalence of the negative class.

This problem has a alternative solution, though, which doesn't require you to throw away any training data: adjusting the cost function. The problem only occurs if you weigh all errors equally, i.e. you tell the classifier to try and get as few mistakes as possible across all the data. So instead of trying to minimize the *number* of errors, you can tell the classifier to minimize the *frequency* of errors, averaged over the two classes. This means that the total weight of errors on the rare class is equal to the total weight of errors on the common class, and so there is no longer any benefit for the classifier to always (or mostly) answer the more prevalent class. This *should* remove any bias in learning, i.e. the classifier should no longer learn trivial strategies based on class frequency rather than real patterns in the data.

When testing the classifier, the problem is that you're unsure what the chance level of errors is, because there are trivial "cheating" classifiers that could get very low error rates simply by always (or mostly) answering the most prevalent class. The solution here is essentially the same: don't throw all errors into the same bag, but look at them separately for each class. A dumb classifier that always gives the same answer will predict the most prevalent class correctly 100% of the time, but get 0% of the other class right, which averages out to the familiar binary chance level of 50%. Any classifier that scores (significantly) higher than that *must* be retrieving some real information from the data. There are more sophisticated ways of looking at this, but that's essentially the intuition.

So in either case, I don't think undersampling is typically the best answer because it's throwing away data, and there other ways of restoring the class balance in your analysis that use all the data.